# Nodejs - script that download all file from ftp to local folder and move on to another ftp folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I am trying to download all files located within a specific folder on a FTP site. The folder is called "IN" (as shown in example code) and contains a number of .csv files.

the requirement are this:

1. donwload to local folder all the csv present on the IN folder
2. move them from IN folder on the FTP to ARCHIVE folder on the ftp folder
3. Merge all the csv file to a new csv with all the content of the csv imported

i'm stuck to the secondo point. I use promise-ftp to do this process and here my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Client = require("promise-ftp");
const sftp = new Client();

sftp
  .connect({
    host: "xxxxx",
    port: 21,
    user: "xxxx",
    password: "xxxxx",
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connected");
    // will return an array of objects with information about all files in the remote folder
    return sftp.list("/htdocs/IN");
  })
  .then(async (data) => {
    // data is the array of objects
    len = data.length;
    // x is one element of the array
    await data.forEach((x) => {
      let remoteFilePath = "/htdocs/IN/" + x.name;
      if (x.type === "-") {
        console.log(x.name);
        sftp
          .get(remoteFilePath)
          .then((stream) => {
            console.log("---------");
            console.log(x.name);
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              stream.once("close", resolve);
              stream.once("error", reject);
              stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("IN/" + x.name));
            });
          })
          .then(() =>{
            sftp
              .rename("/htdocs/IN/" + x.name, "/htdocs/OUT/" + x.name)
              .then(function () {
                console.log("rinominato");
              })
            console.log("qui cancello: " + x.name);
          });
      }
    });
  }).then(() => {
    sftp.end();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, "catch error");
  });
```

Now this script download all the file on my local storage but when i tried to rename it to another folder i receive this error:

```
Unhandled rejection FtpConnectionError: can't perform 'rename' command when connection status is: disconnecting
```

i think that i'm make some mistake on where put the sftp.close function but i'm new on node.js.

Anyone could help me to understand better where i'm wrong?

**Added new version** of the code with more async and await but still not working:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Client = require("promise-ftp");
const ftp = new Client();

const downloadAndStoreFile = async () => {
    await ftp.connect({
      host: "xxxx",
      port: 21,
      user: "xxx",
      password: "xxx",
    });

    console.log ('connected');

    let data = await ftp.list('/htdocs/IN');
    data = data.filter(function (file) {
      return file.type === "-" ? file : null;
    });
    console.log(data);

    data.forEach((file)=>{
        if (file.type === '-'){
          //console.log(file.name);
          const operation = async () => {
            console.log(file.name);
            const stream = await ftp.get("/htdocs/IN/" + file.name);
            const streamResult = await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("IN/" + file.name));
            const renameResult = await ftp.rename("/htdocs/IN/" + file.name, "/htdocs/OUT/" + file.name);
          };
          operation();
        }
    });

    await ftp.end();
};

downloadAndStoreFile();
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the await way to do stuff like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Client = require("promise-ftp");
const sftp = new Client();

sftp
    .connect({
        host: "XXXX",
        port: 21,
        user: "XXX",
        password: "XXX",
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("connected");
        // will return an array of objects with information about all files in the remote folder
        return sftp.list("/htdocs/IN");
    })
    .then(async(data) => {
        // data is the array of objects
        len = data.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            let x = data[i]; // x is one element of the array

            let remoteFilePath = "/htdocs/IN/" + x.name;
            if (x.type === "-") {
                console.log(x.name);
                let stream = sftp.get(remoteFilePath);

                console.log("---------");
                console.log(x.name);

                await stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("IN/" + x.name));

                await sftp.rename("/htdocs/IN/" + x.name, "/htdocs/OUT/" + x.name)
                console.log("rinominato");
                console.log("qui cancello: " + x.name);
            }
        }
    }).then(() => {
        sftp.end();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "catch error");
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried but I receive a similar error: Unhandled rejection FtpConnectionError: can't perform 'rename' command when connection status is: disconnecting. I think that the sftp.end will be reached before the rename process. also with this solution it seems that the files are renamed before i can do the download

Comment: But, your code snippet doesn't show sftp.end

Comment: you are right. Sorry I forgot to add the part that not working :) If I omit the sftp.end() the script works (download all file and rename it to another folder) but If I put the sftp.end() it's now working anymore. I think that the problem is related on the sftp.end() is launched before the renamed process.

Comment: Yep, It's logically incorrect. I will suggest instead of promises, you use await. That way the code will be more readable, as well as you will be able to figure out the solution

Comment: Modified the answer with the await way

Comment: I tried your solution and I got this message: /Users/loganwhitewolf/workspace/vinhood-core/tools/iper/stack.js:5
await sftp
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. I modified some part of the code to use more async and await. I updated the post with the new solution but still not working.. :(

Comment: add another point: if i remove the line     await ftp.end(); from the new script it start to work (download and rename) but the session remain open.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try with the latest code in my answer. Also, please mask the hostname, username and password in the question.

Comment: Now works, so the problem was the forEach statement. Thank you a lot for your help. I understand better now the promise and the async/await.  I updated the credentials :)

Comment: i try to cast a vote but i don't have the reputation to do that but i accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is quite descriptive:

```
Unhandled rejection FtpConnectionError: can't perform 'rename' command when connection status is: disconnecting
```

What we can conclude from it is that `rename` is being called while client tries to disconnect. The problem is with async calls being made in the forEach loop, since you are not waiting for them to settle before ending the connection.

One possible solution would be mapping operations to promise array and calling `Promise.all`.

```
    Promise.all(
      data
       .filter((file) => file.type === "-")
       .map((file) => {
          const operation = async () => {
          const stream = await ftp.get("/htdocs/IN/" + file.name);
          const streamResult = await stream.pipe(
            fs.createWriteStream("IN/" + file.name)
          );
          const renameResult = await ftp.rename(
            "/htdocs/IN/" + file.name,
            "/htdocs/OUT/" + file.name
          );
      };
      return operation();
    })
);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i understand the problem and i solve it with the help of Rinkal.